# Skaffold - How to stop it from pulling the images locally?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, amazon-eks, skaffold

We work with a remote EKS where all of our images reside in.
When we're running Skaffold it checks the gitlab registry cache and if there's a cached image it will always pull it locally and then deploy it remotely to the EKS.

Is there a way to let skaffold deploy it directly to the EKS without pulling it locally first?

For the deployment, we're using helm and the build bellow is an example of what we have inside our skaffold.yamls -

```
build:
  tagPolicy:
    inputDigest: {}
  artifacts:
    - image: web_microservice
      context: ../../
      sync: {}
      custom:
        buildCommand: Build/buildx.sh "Web/Dockerfile" production
        dependencies:
          dockerfile:
            path: Web/Dockerfile
  local:
    useBuildkit: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there was a bug in skaffold so I fixed it and it will be released in the next version (2.10.0).
https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pull/9181

Besides that, there should be a `cluster: {}` inside the build section instead of the `local: useBuildkit: true`.